# have number input correlate to string using substring?

Tags: java

I have to write a program following these guidelines. I have no Idea what I am doing. I have tried working through it, but can't seem to figure out how to get the input to correlate to the substring.

Write a program that transforms 1,2,3...12 into the corresponding month January, February... Make a very long string "January February March... " in which you add spaces such that each month name has the same length. Then use substring to extract the month you want.

Can someone please give me some guidance on this?

We haven't worked with arrays or if statements yet, so I don't believe I should be using any of that either. –

Ok here is what I have so far.

```
public class MonthIdentifier
{
    private String monthNames = "January   February  March     April     May       June      July      August    September October   November  December  ";
    private int monthNumber;

    public MonthIdentifier(int month)
    {
        month = monthNumber;
    }

    public String getMonth()
    {
        int monthNameLength = 10;
        int end = monthNumber * monthNameLength;
        int start = end - monthNameLength;
        return monthNames.substring(start, end);

    }
}
```

Here is the main

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ChooseMonth
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Number 1-12: ");
        int month = input.nextInt();
        MonthIdentifier newMonth = new MonthIdentifier(month);

        newMonth.getMonth();
        String monthName = newMonth.getMonth();
        System.out.println(month + " : " + monthName);


    }
}
```

I have updated my code to what I have so far. I am getting an error:

> exception in thread Main String Index out of range: -10

Also I forgot to mention I have to take user input 1-12 and have it correlate to the substring for that month.

Comment: Post a sample input and output

Comment: Post the attempts you have made.

Comment: Use a pencil and paper. Start with this, what month has the longest name? What is it's length? What is it's length + 1. That is a good value to make all the month names. Next, how could you determine the start and end of any particular month in a String that consists of 12 parts, each of which is the same length (which happens to be a constant you calculated with pencil and paper earlier)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close, let's take your `String monthName` and rename it `monthNames`. Then we can get any month (`mm`) between `1 - 12` from `monthNames` like this,

```
int monthNameLength = 10
int end = mm * monthNameLength; // the length is constant, so we have 12 equal parts.
int start = end - monthNameLength;
return monthNames.substring(start, end);
```

I'll leave it to you to add appropriate error handling and extract it into a nice method. Note, you really only need to pass in an `int`.

**Edit**

Let's make `getMonth()` static and pass in the `monthNumber` and use range checking,

```
public static String getMonth(int monthNumber)
{
  if (monthNumber < 1 || monthNumber > 12) {
    return "ERROR " + monthNumber + " is less then 1 (or greater then 12)";
  }
  int monthNameLength = 10;
  int end = monthNumber * monthNameLength;
  int start = end - monthNameLength;
  return monthNames.substring(start, end);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Huge help. The only thing is I couldn't make it static. I think because the monthNames is outside of the method? but I got it working like it is supposed to. We hadn't gone over any if statements or boolean but I kept thinking of different ways that would have worked using those, just not the way I had to set this program up. Thank again!